# Show that $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\Re(z)}{z}$ doesn't exist.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

> Show that $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\Re(z)}{z}$ doesn't exist.

Let $z=r(\cos(\theta)+i \sin(\theta))$. So $\frac{\Re(z)}{z} =\cos ^2(\theta) - i \cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) $, and $$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\Re(z)}{z} = \lim_{r \to 0} (\cos ^2(\theta) - i \cos(\theta)\sin(\theta))  = (\cos ^2(\theta) - i  \cos(\theta)\sin(\theta))$$

So the limit cannot exist, because it depends of $\theta$.

Am I right? If not, is there existed another approach?

Comment: It looks fine. Anyway, it would suffice to approach $0 \in \mathbb{C}$ first along $\mathbb{R}$ and then along $i\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine.

Alternatively, note that:
$$\lim_{\substack{z\to0\\z\in\Bbb R}}\frac{\Re(z)}z=\lim_{\substack{z\to0\\z\in\Bbb R}}\frac zz=1$$
but:
$$\lim_{\substack{z\to0\\z\in i\Bbb R}}\frac{\Re(z)}z=\lim_{\substack{z\to0\\z\in i\Bbb R}}\frac 0z=0$$
(where $i\Bbb R=\{ix:x\in\Bbb R\}$ is the set of purely imaginary numbers).

Answer (score 1):

Write the function in question as $f(x,y) = \frac{x^{2} - ixy}{x^{2} + y^{2}}$ and note that $f(0,y) = 0$ and $f(x, 0) = 1$.